# How to get the processId/handle of the windows 10 store apps?

Tags: c#

I have the existing code base which returns the handle of the application on the application start. It works perfectly for all the application. But every time I open up the any store app whether be it calculator, alarm or skype. I receive the handle of ApplicationFrameHost rather than that of the particular app. 
But if I query for the Window Caption of the handle using win32Api I get the particular application name.

Why is that I get handle for the ApplicationFrameHost rather than Skype. Is there any way to get the handle of the skype from the ApplicationFrameHost Handle??

Comment: “ApplicationFrameHost.exe” is a central process running on your PC, which is in charge of displaying UWP applications in frames (windows) on your desktop.  In a sense, it's like the APPs parent window or container.  Let me see, if I have some time here, to give you a code example, to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start.  Just add your GetWindowText(), etc ... logic.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        internal struct WINDOWINFO
        {
            public uint ownerpid;
            public uint childpid;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hWndParent, EnumWindowProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName([In]IntPtr hProcess, [In]int dwFlags, [Out]StringBuilder lpExeName, ref int lpdwSize);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]Boolean bInheritHandle, Int32 dwProcessId);

        WinEventDelegate dele = null;

        public delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr parameter);
        delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

        public const UInt32 PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x400;
        public const UInt32 PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x010;

        private const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;
        private const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = 3;

        private static string UWP_AppName(IntPtr hWnd, uint pID)
        {
            WINDOWINFO windowinfo = new WINDOWINFO();
            windowinfo.ownerpid = pID;
            windowinfo.childpid = windowinfo.ownerpid;

            IntPtr pWindowinfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(windowinfo));

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(windowinfo, pWindowinfo, false);

            EnumWindowProc lpEnumFunc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumChildWindowsCallback);
            EnumChildWindows(hWnd, lpEnumFunc, pWindowinfo);

            windowinfo = (WINDOWINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pWindowinfo, typeof(WINDOWINFO));

            IntPtr proc;
            if ((proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, (int)windowinfo.childpid)) == IntPtr.Zero) return null;

            int capacity = 2000;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(capacity);
            QueryFullProcessImageName(proc, 0, sb, ref capacity);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pWindowinfo);

            return sb.ToString(0, capacity);
        }

        private static bool EnumChildWindowsCallback(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            WINDOWINFO info = (WINDOWINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(WINDOWINFO));

            uint pID;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out pID);

            if (pID != info.ownerpid) info.childpid = pID;

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(info, lParam, true);

            return true;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dele = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc);
            IntPtr m_hhook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, IntPtr.Zero, dele, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
        }

        public void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";

            uint pID;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pID);

            textBox1.Text = UWP_AppName(hwnd, pID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This snippet has been a life saver, but it often throws `System.ExecutionEngineException` with no stacktrace, any idea what could be causing it. It mostly fails when I switch to Visual Studio